# Crear un trigger para una bitacora en postgresql y obtener datos de 2 tablas distintas despues de un delete

Tags: sql, postgresql

Hola mi problema es el siguiente
Tengo dos tablas de las cuales se llaman connection y esta tiene las siguientes columnas

boxnum(pk) | date | partnum

boxnum es la pk

luego esta la tabla market que tiene los siguientes campos

boxnumm(PK)(FK) | entrydate | exitdate | existence(boolean)

y lo que quiero hacer es que cada que se elimine un registro del mercado se registren en la tabla que se llama logbook

ID | boxnum | entrydatem | exitdatem | partnum

esto es facil utilizando un trigger que sea disparado por un delete pero el problema que tengo es que quiero que el boxnum de connection se enlace con el de market para asi poder obtener el partnum que tenia en ese momento el registro eliminado y lo que tengo es esto

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insertar_trigger() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $insertar$
DECLARE BEGIN
INSERT INTO public.logbook (boxnum, entrydatem, exitdatem, partnum) SELECT old.boxnumm, old.entrydate, old.exitdate, partnum
FROM public.market me INNER JOIN public.connection cp ON me.boxnumm = cp.boxnum
where cp.boxnum = old.boxnumm;
RETURN NULL;
END;
$insertar$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;


CREATE TRIGGER insertar_bitacora BEFORE DELETE 
ON mercado FOR EACH ROW 
EXECUTE PROCEDURE insertar_trigger();
```

pero como pueden ver uso el before DELETE al hacer esto funciona muy bien el disparador guarda los datos que quiero pero en la tabla mercado el registro nunca se borra, aparece como borrado pero si muestro los campos de esta tabla aparecen de nuevo los que aparenmente se borraron, entonces volvi a cambiar el before por el after pero esto hacia imposible que se cumpliera la parte del where, no se como solucionarlo, si me pudieran ayudar se los agradeceria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya encontre lo que hacia que no funcionara bien era que estoy retornando un null y eso anula el delete por lo tanto esto hacia que se anulara el delete se mandaban los datos pero no se procedia el borrado y con solo cambiar un el RETURN NULL por un RETURN OLD ya funciona como debe.